# zfs pools unavailable, disks shared with other pools

Tags: zfs, zpool, zfsonlinux

My ZFS pool called *data* do not mount anymore after a shutdown.
Maybe there was some automatic update on the computer. I Don't know.

`zpool status` returns
`no pools available`

`zpool import` returns something strange to me

```
pool: data
  id: 14112227688943668786
state: ONLINE
status: The pool is formatted using a legacy on-disk version.
action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier, though
    some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.
config:

    data                                          ONLINE
      raidz3-0                                    ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0543911  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0541901  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0534846  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0559408  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0497883  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0560576  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0535023  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0534837  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0534911  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N0074989  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0531032  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0543358  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0589256  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0560327  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0547220  ONLINE

  pool: data
    id: 17000803019094542855
  state: UNAVAIL
  status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
  action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
    see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
  config:

    data                                           UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz3-0                                     UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0535023  UNAVAIL
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0560483  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0558445  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WCC4N0071139  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WCC4N0074989  UNAVAIL
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0592680  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0497883  UNAVAIL
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0541732  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0589971  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0559406  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0559408  UNAVAIL
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0592326  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0560660  ONLINE
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0589256  UNAVAIL
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WMC4N0535000  ONLINE
```

That is: two pools called *data*:
- one with id 14112227688943668786. state: ONLINE. I will call it *data_unwanted* below.
- one with id 17000803019094542855. state: UNAVAIL. I will call it *data_wanted* below.

*data_unwanted* is a reminiscence of a test I did a long time ago. I think I destroyed the pool after my tests. Then I created *data_wanted* and enjoyed it for 2 years without any problem. Note that I rebooted a few times to update the system during these 2 years without any problem.

I have two other pools of 15 drives each that got their names "duplicated" in the same way.

I noticed that the hard drives that are UNVAILABLE in *data_wanted* are those that are "common" with *data_unwanted* or one of the other two newly appeared *_unwanted* pools. For example, `scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WCC4N0074989` is UNAVAIL in *data_wanted* while it appears ONLINE with name `ata-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WCC4N0074989` in *data_unwanted*.

For some reason, it seems that *data_unwanted* and two friends popped-up back from past at reboot, with priority over *data_wanted*, and as it uses some of the drives needed by *data_wanted*, it makes *data_wanted* UNAVAIL.

I can't find a solution to this. The data is important, I thought everything was safe with the raidz3 level, good RAM, power redundancy, but ...

Oh, and uname -a reports:
   `Linux backupmachine 3.13.0-53-generic #89~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 17:42:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
That's Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Comment: All of this information is good, but can you provide some details on the actual hardware involved? Controllers? Disk type? Chassis?

Comment: @ewwhite Could you please tell me the optimal way of reporting this? Is there a linux command that would report this perfectly?

Comment: @ewwhite Well, the drives are obviously WD30EFRXs, so WD Red NAS 3TB drives.

Comment: @max The fact that `zpool status` reports `no pools available` isn't unexpected; that command only lists *currently imported pools*. Have you tried simply importing `17000803019094542855` by pool ID? What was the result of that? Another thing you can try is to create a directory (doesn't have to be under /dev) containing symlinks to *only* the required devices (including partitions) and using `zpool import -d /dev/where/ever 17000803019094542855` to import the pool from there instead. If that works, you're in the green as far as data is concerned, and all we need to do is clean up the import.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you can edit the question to indicate the variant and release of ZFS you're running. Since you tagged this [zfsonlinux] I *suspect* you're running [ZFS On Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/), but which version of it is currently installed?

Comment: Please post the output of the commands 'zdb -l /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68_WD-WCC4N0074989-part1' and 'zdb -Ce 17000803019094542855'